# How will I increment string numbers in my jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying this to make the last digit increment, it has 3 numbers on it for example, ABC123-DE45-000 How will I make the last 0 increment to 1, it will look like ABC123-DE45-001,ABC123-DE45-002,ABC123-DE45-003 and so on and so fort, I tried doing this code, turns out that the 000 will increment into 1 not 001 and I get it because (\d+) finds a string which has a number then converts it into Integer, but is it possible for my problem to be like what I am asking for? Thanks for the answer.

Here is my script

```
    function addInputs(pass) {
       var n = pass.value && parseInt(pass.value, 10);
           if (isNaN(n)) {
           return;
           }
    }


         $('button').click(function() {
             var value = $('#sel_control_num').val();
             for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        
                value = value.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(match, n) {
                     console.log(value);
                     return ++n; 
                 });
                 $('#parent')[0].innerHTML += '<br>' + value;
        
             }
         })
```

Here is my HTML

```
         <div>
         <label> Control No </label>
              <input name="get_control_num" style="text-transform:uppercase"
               class="form-control" id="sel_control_num" readonly>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label> Quantity </label>
              <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number"
               onchange="addInputs(this)" />
              <br>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Control Number </button>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group" id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Get the last three chars and use ++;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Lookbehind`, you can match `-` before the number and do:

```
value = value.replace(/(?<=-)\d{3}/g, function(match, n) { 
             const nextValue = ++match; 
             return ('000'+nextValue).slice(-3); 
         });
```